# How to add image processing to compositor workflows

Tags: python, node-editor, compositing-nodes, image

I'm looking for a way to add image processing to the compositor in Blender 2.8 or later. I'd like to use either a python script or an external program to process images as part of a compositor workflow. Is there a way to add customer logic into the compositor.

Approaches considered so far:

1. Creating a custom node. It appears the only way to generate a custom compositor node is by modifying the source code for Blender and recompiling.
2. Using the Image input and Image output nodes. However, these node only allow a fixed name and there is no way to block execution while waiting for an external program to process an image.

Are there any add-ons or other approaches to add image processing algorithms into the compositor?

Comment: [This developer task](https://developer.blender.org/T54272) may be useful. With API, `bpy.data.images['Image'].pixels`, you can only get a list of pixels (4 floats for each pixel, RGBA-format) to perform some math on them. Doesn't work for multilayer images.